# ASP.Net web application gets hanged due to connection can not be opened

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have developed a ASP.Net web application with SQL Server 2005 as a back-end and application is configured on IIS 5.1.

Application works fine for few transactions (Insert, Update), suddenly it can't connect to SQL Server (can't open connection), hence gives time out expired.

I am closing connection, transaction every time after a database call for Insert, update.

I have specified pooling explicitly in connection string also, but didn't work.

Comment: Is this happen same when you run your aplication under VisualStudio ?

Comment: Try put your code, which is creating an issue.

Comment: POst `CodeBehind` n `Error msg` it helps in understanding, so one can give relevant gudience/answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the most accepted method of doing this is through the
CommandTimeout property of the SqlCommand object. Set it to 0 for an infinite timeout.

```
The default timeout is 30 seconds.
```

Comment: Error I am geting is as below:                                     Error : Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Connection timeout property in your webconfig, also check the database regarding how many connections it supports and then check your connection pool size. Also the timeout property you set in webconfig relates to the time taken to establish the connection to db and the command time out property in your code relates to the time your query can run before it is timed out.